# Tick marks around the perimeter, not just bottom and left

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like my axes and tick marks to wrap around the entire chart, not just top and bottom. In other words, I want the tick marks to look like this:

[image: Tick marks all around]

Not this:

[image: Tick marks bottom and left only]

How do I make this happen?

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
figure;
hold on;
plot(indeces(1:n), mod_X_L_final(1:n), 'Color',nColor, 'Linestyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',20);
plot(indeces(n+1:n+m), mod_X_L_final(n+1:n+m), 'Color',mColor, 'Linestyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',20);
set(gca, 'fontsize', 20, 'fontname', 'times');
ax1 = gca;
ax1.XTick = linspace(1,n+m,n+m);
ax1.YTick = [0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi];
ax1.YTickLabel = {'0','\pi/2','\pi','3\pi/2','2\pi'};
ylim([0, 2*pi]);

figure;
plot(tStDev, stDevM, 'Color',mColor, 'Linewidth',3); 
ylim([-pi/2, 3*pi/2]);
set(gca, 'fontsize', 20,  'fontname', 'times');
ax1 = gca;
ax1.YTick = [-pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2];%, 2*pi];
ax1.YTickLabel = {'-\pi/2','0','\pi/2','\pi','3\pi/2'};%,'2\pi'};
xlabel('Time', 'VerticalAlignment','top',  'fontsize', 20, 'fontname','helvetica', 'fontangle','italic');   
ylabel('$\Delta \Phi$','interpreter','latex')
```

Comment: Could you post the code you used to generate this plot?

Comment: Or try putting your `hold on` after the first `plot` call (and before the second call, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`box`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/box.html) to control how to display the axis outline.

> `box on` displays the box outline around the current axes. This option sets the `Box` property of the current axes to `'on'`.

Hence, add

```
box on
```

say, after `hold on` command in your (non-verifiable) example above.